# JavaScript SUM and GROUP BY of JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, group-by, sum

This is my first attempt at doing JavaScript with some JSON data objects and need some advice on the proper way to attain my goal.

Some server-side code actually generates a JSON formatted string that I have to work with and assign it to a string:

```
var dataString='$DATASTRING$';
```

But the end-result I have to work with after the server substitutes its data (without the \r\n, of course):

```
var dataString='[ 
 { "category" : "Search Engines", "hits" : 5, "bytes" : 50189 },
 { "category" : "Content Server", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 17308 },
 { "category" : "Content Server", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 47412 },
 { "category" : "Search Engines", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 7601 },
 { "category" : "Business", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 2847 },
 { "category" : "Content Server", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 24210 },
 { "category" : "Internet Services", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 3690 },
 { "category" : "Search Engines", "hits" : 6, "bytes" : 613036 },
 { "category" : "Search Engines", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 2858 } 
]';
```

And then I can change it to an object to work with.

```
var dataObject=eval("("+dataString+")");
```

This allows me to access the data individual rows of data, but I need to sum, group by, and order the values.

I need to the equivalent of an SQL statement like this:

```
SELECT category, sum(hits), sum(bytes) 
FROM dataObject
GROUP BY category
ORDER BY sum(bytes) DESC
```

My desired output would be an object like this that I can further process:

```
var aggregatedObject='[ 
 { "category" : "Search Engines", "hits" : 13, "bytes" : 673684 },
 { "category" : "Content Server", "hits" : 3, "bytes" : 88930 },
 { "category" : "Internet Services", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 3690 },
 { "category" : "Business", "hits" : 1, "bytes" : 2847 } 
]';
```

...but i don't know where to start.

I could loop through all the category values and find the unique categories first, then loop again and sum the hits and bytes, then again to sort, but it seems there has got to be an easier way.

prototype.js (1.7) is already included on the client page, but I could add Underscore, jQuery, or some other small library if I had to.

I just don't know what would be best, easiest, smallest with the least amount of code to process the query.

Any suggestions?

Comment: [LINQ to JS](http://linqjs.codeplex.com/) might not have *everything* you need, but it might be helpful for you

Comment: Not bad. Good place to start looking, but still needs jQuery for the aggrgate functions. A little more than I wanted. could come in handy for another project I have in mind. Thanks

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use the native functions `.reduce()` to aggregrate the data, and then `.sort()` to sort by `bytes`.

```
var result = dataObject.reduce(function(res, obj) {
    if (!(obj.category in res))
        res.__array.push(res[obj.category] = obj);
    else {
        res[obj.category].hits += obj.hits;
        res[obj.category].bytes += obj.bytes;
    }
    return res;
}, {__array:[]}).__array
                .sort(function(a,b) { return b.bytes - a.bytes; });
```

If you're supporting older implementations, you'll need to use a [shim for `.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#Compatibility).

Comment: Beautiful. Does exactly what I want and only needs a small shim for reduce. (even works in IE6 :) I think that was the key I was missing because I saw .reduce referred to but could never get it to work. seems to have the lowest overhead and does what I need. Awesome.

Comment: hmmm. Now I wonder if there's an easy way to graph this? I was just going to do a text table, but maybe a chart for the bytes or the hits. Any good graphing routines out there?

Comment: @LordChariot: Google will likely show you quite a few nice libraries for graphing. Give a few a try first, and then ask a question if you get stuck on something. `:)`

Comment: WoW... I also searching for this... Thanks.. 1 Up for the answer... :)

Comment: Seem your callback function is not a pure function. It changes the original array. So that we cannot reuse the initial data to process another step. Btw, thanks for the answer.

Comment: Perfect solution for compact functions.

Answer (score 10):

If you go the [LINQ.js](https://github.com/mihaifm/linq) route, you can do it like this:

```js
var aggregatedObject = Enumerable.From(dataArray)
    .GroupBy("$.category", null, function (key, g) {
        return {
          category: key,
          hits: g.Sum("$.hits"),
          bytes: g.Sum("$.bytes")
        }
    })
    .ToArray();
```

#### Working demo with Stack Snippets:

```js
var dataArray = [ 
  { category: "Search Engines", hits: 5, bytes: 50189 },
  { category: "Content Server", hits: 1, bytes: 17308 },
  { category: "Content Server", hits: 1, bytes: 47412 },
  { category: "Search Engines", hits: 1, bytes: 7601  },
  { category: "Business",       hits: 1, bytes: 2847  },
  { category: "Content Server", hits: 1, bytes: 24210 },
  { category: "Internet ",      hits: 1, bytes: 3690  },
  { category: "Search Engines", hits: 6, bytes: 613036 },
  { category: "Search Engines", hits: 1, bytes: 2858  } 
];

var aggregatedObject = Enumerable.From(dataArray)
    .GroupBy("$.category", null, function (key, g) {
        return {
          category: key,
          hits: g.Sum("$.hits"),
          bytes: g.Sum("$.bytes")
        }
    })
    .ToArray();

console.log(aggregatedObject);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/linq.js/2.2.0.2/linq.min.js"></script>
```

**Further Reading**: [linqjs group by with a sum](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17824008/1366033)

Answer (score 2):

Given the dataString above, the below code seems to work. It goes through each object; if the category exists in the `groupedObjects` array, its hits and bytes are added to the existing object. Otherwise, it is considered new and added to the groupedObjects array.

This solution makes use of underscore.js and jQuery

Here's a jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/R3p4c/2/

```
var objects = $.parseJSON(dataString);
var categories = new Array();
var groupedObjects = new Array();
var i = 0;

_.each(objects,function(obj){
    var existingObj;
    if($.inArray(obj.category,categories) >= 0) {
        existingObj = _.find(objects,function(o){return o.category === obj.category; });
        existingObj.hits += obj.hits;
        existingObj.bytes += obj.bytes;
    } else {
        groupedObjects[i] = obj;
        categories[i] = obj.category;
        i++;
  }
});

groupedObjects = _.sortBy(groupedObjects,function(obj){ return obj.bytes; }).reverse();
```

Comment: Yes. Does exactly what I wanted it to do. I put in the actual full dataset I receive (1000+ array elements) into jsfiddle and it came out with the correct values. Downside is it needs both Underscore and jQuery. I was hoping to reduce the amount of baggage I had to include. (Can't hot link to external because it's likely on a closed network) But overall i love the flexibility for some other stuff i might be doing soon.

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj = [{Poz:'F1',Cap:10},{Poz:'F1',Cap:5},{Poz:'F1',Cap:5},{Poz:'F2',Cap:20},{Poz:'F1',Cap:5},{Poz:'F1',Cap:15},{Poz:'F2',Cap:5},{Poz:'F3',Cap:5},{Poz:'F4',Cap:5},{Poz:'F1',Cap:5}];
Array.prototype.sumUnic = function(name, sumName){
    var returnArr = [];
    var obj = this;
    for(var x = 0; x<obj.length; x++){
        if((function(source){
            if(returnArr.length == 0){
                return true;
            }else{
                for(var y = 0; y<returnArr.length; y++){
                    var isThere = [];
                    if(returnArr[y][name] == source[name]){
                        returnArr[y][sumName] = parseInt(returnArr[y][sumName]) + parseInt(source[sumName]);
                        return false;
                    }else{
                        isThere.push(source);
                    }
                }
                if(isThere.length>0)returnArr.push(source);
                return false;
            }
        })(obj[x])){
            returnArr.push(obj[x]);
        }
    }
    return returnArr;
}
obj.sumUnic('Poz','Cap');
// return "[{"Poz":"F1","Cap":45},{"Poz":"F2","Cap":25},{"Poz":"F3","Cap":5},{"Poz":"F4","Cap":5}]"
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi here is one solution written by me  Visit: [aggregate_groupby_js on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aggregate_groupby_js)
    or in [aggregate_groupby_js on github](http://github:%20https://github.com/naimsulejmani/aggregate.js)

The javascript library for using aggregate functions on array of objects. Basic functions like SUM, MIN, MAX, AVG, DISTINCT_COUNT for entire javascript objects

Example:

```
var arr = [{`"shape"`:`"square"`,`"color"`:`"red"`,`"used"`:1,`"instances"`:1},
    {`"shape"`:`"square"`,`"color"`:`"red"`,`"used"`:2,`"instances"`:1},
    {`"shape"`:`"circle"`,`"color"`:`"blue"`,`"used"`:0,`"instances"`:0},
    {`"shape"`:`"square"`,`"color"`:`"blue"`,`"used"`:4,`"instances"`:4},
    {`"shape"`:`"circle"`,`"color"`:`"red"`,"`used"`:1,`"instances"`:1},
    {`"shape"`:`"circle"`,`"color"`:`"red"`,`"used"`:1,`"instances"`:0},
    {`"shape"`:`"square"`,`"color"`:`"blue"`,`"used"`:4,`"instances"`:5}, 
    {`"shape"`:`"square"`,`"color"`:`"red"`,`"used"`:2,`"instances"`:1}];

// Specify columns
    var columns =[`"used"`, `"instances"`];

// Initialize object
    var gb = new GroupBy(arr,columns);
// or
    var gb = new GroupBy(arr,[`"used"`, `"instances"`]);

// Call the aggregate functions    
    gb.sum();
    gb.min();
    gb.max();
    gb.avg();
    gb.distinctCount();
```