# linqjs group by with a sum

Tags: javascript, jquery, linq, linq.js

This might seems like an easy question but I'm struggling with the linqjs syntax.

Given the following basic JSON:

```json
{
    "DateEvent": "2013-04-23 14:00:00Z",
    "DateRecord": "2013-04-23 14:00:00Z",
    "Amount": -9500,
    "Type": {
        "Description": "Capital"
    },
    "Currency": {
        "ID": "USD"
    }
}
```

Using linqjs how can I return the total for each currency?

```js
Enumerable.From(data)
    .GroupBy("{ currency: $.Currency.ID }", null, function (key, g) {
        var result = {
            currency: key.currency,
            total: g.Sum($.Amount)
        }
    });
```

The code above doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You almost had it. Your key selector in your GroupBy and Sum is incorrect. Also the key selector needs to be a string. Try the following:

```
var result = Enumerable.from(data).groupBy("$.Currency.ID", null,
    function (key, g) {
        var result = {
            currency: key,
            total: g.sum("$.Amount")
        }
        return result;
    }).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

I am the author of the open-source project http://www.jinqJs.com

You could easily do it by executing:

```
new jinqJs().from(data).groupBy('Currency').sum('Amount').select();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand further on this question.

The following syntax will group the data by an additional field:

```
var result = Enumerable.from(data)
                       .groupBy("{ currency: $.Currency.ID, type: $.Type.Description }", null,
                            function (key, g) {
                                var result = {
                                     currency: key.currency,
                                     type: key.type,
                                     total: g.Sum("$.Amount")
                                }
                                return result;
                                }, function (x) { return x.currency + ':' + x.type }).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an array of objects that looks like that, you can write your query like this:

```
var query = Enumerable.from(data)
    .groupBy(
        "{ Currency: $.Currency.ID, Type: $.Type.Description }",
        "$.Amount",
        "{ Currency: $.Currency, Type: $.Type, Total: $$.Sum() }"
    )
    .ToArray();
```

Personally I find using the lambda string syntax more succinct and preferable. Mixing lambdas and functions leads to messier code IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

### Update with Native JS

With widespread support for JS operations in nearly any browser and the proliferation of build tools to compile down when necessary, unless you're *already* importing linqjs, I'd recommend going with a *native JS approach*.

```js
const grouped = data.reduce((acc, el) => {
  const key = el.Currency.ID
  const prev = acc[key] ?? 0
  acc[key] = prev + el.Amount;
  return acc;
}, {})
```

### Demo in Stack Snippets

```js
const data = [
    {
        "Amount": 5,
        "Currency": { "ID": "USD" }
    },
    {
        "Amount": 10,
        "Currency": { "ID": "USD" }
    },
    {
        "Amount": 20,
        "Currency": { "ID": "CAN" }
    }
]

const grouped = data.reduce((acc, el) => {
  const key = el.Currency.ID
  const prev = acc[key] ?? 0
  acc[key] = prev + el.Amount;
  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(grouped)

// {
//     "USD": 15,
//     "CAN": 20
// }
```

**See Also**: [How to group by and sum an array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19233283/1366033)