# Sum JavaScript object propertyA values with the same object propertyB in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, reduce

How would one take a JavaScript array of objects, such as

```js
objArr = [
    {key:"Mon Sep 23 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400", val:42},
    {key:"Mon Sep 24 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400", val:78},
    {key:"Mon Sep 25 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400", val:23},
    {key:"Mon Sep 23 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400", val:54} // <- duplicate key
]
```

and merge duplicate keys by summing the values?

In order to get something like this:

```
reducedObjArr = [
    {key:"Mon Sep 23 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400", val:96},
    {key:"Mon Sep 24 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400", val:78},
    {key:"Mon Sep 25 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400", val:23}
]
```

I have tried iterating and adding to a new array, but this didn't work:

```
var reducedObjArr = [];
var item = null, key = null;
for(var i=0; i<objArr.length; i++) {
    item = objArr[i];
    key = Object.keys(item)[0];
    item = item[key];

    if(!result[key]) {
        result[key] = item;
    } else {
       result[key] += item;
    }
}a
```

Comment: Why are you doing `key = Object.keys(item)[0]; item=item[key];` ? You already know the name is `key`, so just do `item.key` or `objArr[i].key`. Also, using the `[0]` index won't necessarily always give you the same property.

Comment: Thanks lookinig for same ,,

Comment: Will it work without quoting the strings, e.g. `Mon Sep 23 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400`?

Comment: A TypeScript alternative is discussed in [Group by and sum on multiple keys maintaining type safety](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76272301/8929855)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should be assigning each object not found to the result with its `.key` property.

If it is found, then you need to add its `.val`.

```
var temp = {};
var obj = null;
for(var i=0; i < objArr.length; i++) {
   obj=objArr[i];

   if(!temp[obj.key]) {
       temp[obj.key] = obj;
   } else {
       temp[obj.key].val += obj.val;
   }
}
var result = [];
for (var prop in temp)
    result.push(temp[prop]);
```

---

Also, part of the problem was that you were reusing the `item` variable to reference the value of `.key`, so you lost reference to the object.

Answer (score 17):

Rather than using a *for* loop and pushing values, you can directly use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Map) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
let objArr = [
  {key: 'Mon Sep 23 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400', val: 42},
  {key: 'Mon Sep 24 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400', val: 78},
  {key: 'Mon Sep 25 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400', val: 23},
  {key: 'Mon Sep 23 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400', val: 54}
];

// first, convert data into a Map with reduce
let counts = objArr.reduce((prev, curr) => {
  let count = prev.get(curr.key) || 0;
  prev.set(curr.key, curr.val + count);
  return prev;
}, new Map());

// then, map your counts object back to an array
let reducedObjArr = [...counts].map(([key, value]) => {
  return {key, value}
})

console.log(reducedObjArr);
```

Comment: Can a seperate count be also added as well using map/reduce. Example : 23rd sep, count will be 2, for 24th & 25 count will be 1.

Comment: Yep! You'd just do something like `count + 1` instead of `curr.val + count` in the `prev.set` call

Answer (score 11):

Simpler reduce than posted elsewhere since it does not use a Map element

```js
const objArr = [
{key:"Mon Sep 23 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400", val:42},
{key:"Mon Sep 24 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400", val:78},
{key:"Mon Sep 25 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400", val:23},
{key:"Mon Sep 23 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400", val:54}];

const output = objArr.reduce((accumulator, cur) => {
  let date = cur.key;
  let found = accumulator.find(elem => elem.key === date)
  if (found) found.val += cur.val;
  else accumulator.push(cur);
  return accumulator;
}, []);

console.log(output)
```

Comment: Still, an explanation would be in order. E.g., in what way is it simpler? What is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58951753/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: It’s not using a map. Updated. It is just simpler code.

Answer (score 5):

You could use a hash table for the grouping by `key`.

```js
var array = [{ key: 'Mon Sep 23 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400', val: 42 }, { key: 'Mon Sep 24 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400', val: 78 }, { key: 'Mon Sep 25 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400', val: 23 }, { key: 'Mon Sep 23 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400', val: 54}],
    grouped = [];

array.forEach(function (o) {
    if (!this[o.key]) {
        this[o.key] = { key: o.key, val: 0 };
        grouped.push(this[o.key]);
    }
    this[o.key].val += o.val;
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Another approach is to collect all key/value pairs in a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and format the final array with [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and a callback for the objects.

```js
var array = [{ key: 'Mon Sep 23 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400', val: 42 }, { key: 'Mon Sep 24 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400', val: 78 }, { key: 'Mon Sep 25 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400', val: 23 }, { key: 'Mon Sep 23 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400', val: 54 }],
    grouped = Array.from(
        array.reduce((m, { key, val }) => m.set(key, (m.get(key) || 0) + val), new Map),
        ([key, val]) => ({ key, val })
    );

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: how to add multiple keys?

Comment: @klent, replace `val` in `this[o.key].val += o.val;` with your property to add.

Comment: Sorry, I've meant how to add another condition before it adds for example if their's another property called 'category'. I want to check key and category.

Comment: take an array for the keys to group, like `groups = ['foo', 'bar']`, inside the `forEach` use `var key = groups.map(k => o[k]).join('|');` and then use `this[key]` instead of `this[o.key]`. maybe omit `this` at all and use a global variable for the object for grouping.

Comment: how to sum same values in object 
if my obj something like this 
```obj = [
{ menu: "apple", amount: 3},
{ menu: "apple", amount: 1},
{menu: "melon", amount: 10},
{menu: "stawberry", amount: 7}
];```

i want the ouput is ```[
{menu: apple, total: 4},
{menu: melon,  total: 10},
and..........
]``` @NinaScholz

Comment: @ZumDummi, you need to reduce the array by finding same `menu` properties and update `amount`.

Comment: can we just use loops, because reduce and some magic functions not allow at my school for now:D we learn old style method:D

Comment: in this case, you better take an object as hash table for the object for accumulation and check against it, if not exists.

Comment: The second approach doesn't seem to work. Values are NaN.

Comment: Can a seperate count be also added as well using map/reduce. Example : 23rd sep, count will be 2, for 24th & 25 count will be 1.

Comment: How can we use a property of the key if the key is an object itself instead of being a string inside the array data. For example instead of accessing the 'key' in "var array" accessing 'key.username'?

Answer (score 3):

```js
var objArr = [
{key:"Mon Sep 23 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400", val:42},
{key:"Mon Sep 24 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400", val:78},
{key:"Mon Sep 25 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400", val:23},
{key:"Mon Sep 23 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400", val:54}]

var targetObj = {};
for (var i = 0; i < objArr.length; i++) {
  if (!targetObj.hasOwnProperty(objArr[i].key)) {
    targetObj[objArr[i].key] = 0;
  }
  targetObj[objArr[i].key] += objArr[i].val;
}

console.log(targetObj);
```

Comment: OP wants the same key/value pairs, but with the `val` consolidated.

Answer (score 2):

One can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) with an object to store the values for each key.

```js
let arr = [{key:'Mon Sep 23 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400', val:42},{key:'Mon Sep 24 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400', val:78},{key:'Mon Sep 25 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400', val:23},{key:'Mon Sep 23 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400', val:54}];
let res = Object.values(arr.reduce((acc, curr)=>{
  (acc[curr.key] = acc[curr.key] || {key: curr.key, val: 0}).val += curr.val;
  return acc;
}, {}));
console.log(res);
```

In newer browsers, [logical nullish assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment) can be used.

```js
let arr = [{key:'Mon Sep 23 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400', val:42},{key:'Mon Sep 24 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400', val:78},{key:'Mon Sep 25 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400', val:23},{key:'Mon Sep 23 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400', val:54}];
let res = Object.values(arr.reduce((acc, curr)=>{
  (acc[curr.key] ??= {key: curr.key, val: 0}).val += curr.val;
  return acc;
}, {}));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Ah, finally a non-"try this" answer!

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It should help.

```js
var arr1 = [
  { name: 'besart', value: 12 },
  { name: 'astrit', value: 10 },
  { name: 'astrit', value: 10 },
  { name: 'besar', value: 18 },
  { name: 'besar', value: 3 },
  { name: 'astrit', value: 3 },
  { name: 'besart', value: 3 },
  { name: 'besart', value: 10 },
  { name: 'besar', value: 0 },
];
var arr2 = [];
var emri = "";
var value = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
  emri = arr1[0].name;
  value += arr1[0].value;
  for (var j = 1; j < arr1.length; j++) {
    if (emri == arr1[j].name) {
      value += arr1[j].value;
      arr1.splice(j, 1);
      j--;
    }
  }
  arr1.splice(0, 1);
  arr2[i] = {
    name: emri,
    value: value
  };
  value = 0;
}
console.log(arr2);
```

Below is another solution that uses only one loop (a *while* loop):

```js
var arr1 = [
  { name: 'besart', value: 12 },
  { name: 'astrit', value: 10 },
  { name: 'astrit', value: 10 },
  { name: 'besar', value: 18 },
  { name: 'besar', value: 3 },
  { name: 'astrit', value: 3 },
  { name: 'besart', value: 3 },
  { name: 'besart', value: 10 },
  { name: 'besar', value: 0 },
];

var arr2 = [];
var emri = "";
var value = 0;
var i = 1;
var j = 0;

while (arr1.length != 0) {
  emri = arr1[0].name;
  if (emri == arr1[i].name) {
    value += arr1[i].value;
    arr1.splice(i, 1);
    i--;
  }
  i++;
  if (i == arr1.length) {
    value += arr1[0].value;
    i = 1;
    arr2[j] = {
      name: emri,
      value: value
    };
    j++;
    value = 0;
    arr1.splice(0, 1);
  }
}
console.log(arr2)
```

Comment: Where did you copy this from? The input data is from [Astrit Spanca's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19233283/sum-javascript-object-propertya-values-with-the-same-object-propertyb-in-an-arra/57365002#57365002). Does it even answer the question? What is the relation between some of the input data and your user name?

Comment: In any case, an explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57372407/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: OK, the OP has left the building (*"Last seen more than 2 years ago"*). There is not much value in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative for you, but similar to that of [Explosion Pills](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19233461/295783). It reuses the original array rather than creating a new one or a different object. The sort may not be necessary and will slow things down a little, but it could be removed.

JavaScript

```
function reduceMyObjArr(arr) {
    var temp = {},
        index;

    for (index = arr.length - 1; index >= 0; index -= 1) {
        key = arr[index].key;
        if (temp.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            arr[temp[key]].val += arr[index].val;
            arr.splice(index, 1);
        } else {
            temp[key] = index;
        }
    }

    arr.sort(function (a, b) {
        if (a.key === b.key) {
            return 0;
        }

        if (a.key < b.key) {
            return -1;
        }

        return 1;
    });

    return arr;
}

var myObjArr = [{
    key: "Mon Sep 23 2013 00: 00: 00 GMT - 0400",
    val: 42
}, {
    key: "Mon Sep 24 2013 00: 00: 00 GMT - 0400",
    val: 78
}, {
    key: "Mon Sep 25 2013 00: 00: 00 GMT - 0400",
    val: 23
}, {
    key: "Mon Sep 23 2013 00: 00: 00 GMT - 0400",
    val: 54
}];

reduceMyObjArr(myObjArr);

console.log(myObjArr);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/kZvzc/)

And a [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/reduce-custom-array-of-objects) that compares this (with and without the sort) against the accepted answer. You can improve the performance test by extending the data set.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using the JavaScript linq framework which is exactly same as an SQL statement which is given desired output with less written code and effective and found at linq.js.

```js
var objArr =
[
{key:'Mon Sep 23 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400', val:42},
{key:'Mon Sep 24 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400', val:78},
{key:'Mon Sep 25 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400', val:23},
{key:'Mon Sep 23 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400', val:54}
];


var aggregatedObject = Enumerable.From(objArr)
        .GroupBy("$.key", null,
                 function (key, g) {
                     return {
                       key: key,
                       contributions: g.Sum("$.val")
                     }
        })
        .ToArray();

console.log(aggregatedObject);
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/linq.js/2.2.0.2/linq.min.js"></script>
```

Which is pretty easy as compare to looping.

Comment: This is confusing. There is also Microsoft's [LINQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) (.NET/C#). Can you [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38295204/edit) a (non-naked) link (URL) to "the JavaScript linq framework"? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38295204/edit), not here in comments. (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Answer (score 0):

Recently I needed a similar implementation and I used a similar solution offered by some guy that used the *reduce* function.

A few days later I wanted to implement something similar by myself and here is the result.

```
const users = [
        { id: 1, name: 'ernest', spent: 40 },
        { id: 2, name: 'ernest', spent: 40 },
        { id: 3, name: 'astrit', spent: 22 },
        { id: 4, name: 'astrit', spent: 2956 },
        { id: 5, name: 'astrit', spent: 22 },
        { id: 6, name: 'besart', spent: 40 },
        { id: 7, name: 'besart', spent: 100},
        { id: 8, name: 'besart', spent: 4000 }
    ];

const sum = [];

users.forEach(el => {
    if(sum.length === 0) {
        delete el.id;
        sum.push(el);
    }
    else
    {
        const get = () => {
            for(let i = 0; i < sum.length; i++) {
                if(sum[i].name === el.name) {
                    return { stat: true, id: i };
                }
            }
        }

        let i = get();
        if(i) {
            sum[i.id].spent += el.spent;
        }
        else
        {
            delete el.id;
            sum.push(el);
        }
    }
});

console.log(sum);
```

Output:

```
[ { name: 'ernest', spent: 80 }, { name: 'astrit', spent: 3000 }, { name: 'besart', spent: 4140 } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function sumGroupBy(array, groupColumn, valueColumn) {
    var res = []
    array.forEach((item) => {
         if(res.map((el) => el[groupColumn]).includes(item[groupColumn])) {
             res.filter((el) => el[groupColumn] == item[groupColumn])[0][valueColumn] += item[valueColumn]
         } else {
             eval(`res.push({${groupColumn}: "${item[groupColumn]}", ${valueColumn}: ${item[valueColumn]} })`)
         }
    });
    return res;
}

const pets = [
    {type:"Dog", age:12},
    {type:"Cat", age:13},
    {type:"Dog", age:6}, 
    {type:"Cat", age:18}
];
    
console.log(sumGroupBy(pets, 'type', 'age' ))
// [ { type: 'Dog', age: 18 }, { type: 'Cat', age: 31 } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more general function that you can use to group an array of objects based on a specified key `groupKey` and calculate the sum of a specified property `sumKey`:

```
function groupAndSum(arr, groupKey, sumKey) {
  return Object.values(
    arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
      const group = curr[groupKey];
      acc[group] = acc[group] || {
        [groupKey]: group,
        [sumKey]: 0
      };
      acc[group][sumKey] += curr[sumKey];
      return acc;
    }, {})
  );
}
```

**Demo:**

```js
let objArr = [{ key: 'Mon Sep 23 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400', val: 42 }, { key: 'Mon Sep 24 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400', val: 78 }, { key: 'Mon Sep 25 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400', val: 23 }, { key: 'Mon Sep 23 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400', val: 54 } ];

function groupAndSum(arr, groupKey, sumKey) {
  return Object.values(
    arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
      const group = curr[groupKey];
      acc[group] = acc[group] || {
        [groupKey]: group,
        [sumKey]: 0
      };
      acc[group][sumKey] += curr[sumKey];
      return acc;
    }, {})
  );
}
console.log(groupAndSum(objArr, 'key', 'val'))
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
function mergeDuplicatesBy(array, getKey, mergeWith) {
  const buff = {}
  array.forEach(function (arrayElement) {
    const key = getKey(arrayElement)
    const alreadyExistingVal = buff[key]
    if (alreadyExistingVal) {
      buff[key] = mergeWith(alreadyExistingVal, arrayElement)
    } else {
      buff[key] = arrayElement
    }
  })
  return Object.values(buff)
}

mergeDuplicatesBy(
  arr,
  x => x.name,
  (x, y) => ({ name: x.name, foo: x.foo + y.foo })
)
```