# Javascript: Merging 2 or more Objects in the Same Array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Any idea how to restructure a data structure like this

```js
var data = [
  [{
    jan: 10,
    feb: 20,
    mar: 30,
    type: "one"
  },
  {
    jan: 20,
    feb: 10,
    mar: 40,
    type: "one"
  }],
  [
    {
    jan: 10,
    feb: 20,
    mar: 30,
    type: "two"
  },
  {
    jan: 20,
    feb: 10,
    mar: 40,
    type: "two"
  }]
]

console.log(data)
```

into something like this?

```js
var data = [
  {
    jan: 30,
    feb: 30,
    mar: 70,
    type: "one"
  },
    {
    jan: 30,
    feb: 30,
    mar: 70,
    type: "two"
  }
]

console.log(data)
```

As seen in the example, objects in the same array are merged and the `jan` , `feb` and `mar` keys are added.

I'm at the end of my wits.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Show us what you've tried?

Comment: reduce/map ? ...

Comment: hash table ...?

Comment: You need to describe the merging rules more specific. As I can see, numbers are summed up. But what should happen to strings? Is it guarantied that they are the same for every object?

Comment: as shown above the strings or the `type` in every array they only have the same strings so strings will remain as it is after is simplified.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sum javascript object propertyA values with same object propertyB in array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19233283/sum-javascript-object-propertya-values-with-same-object-propertyb-in-array-of-ob)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map` and `reduce` functions on javascript arrays to achieve your result.

Use `map` to iterate over the sub arrays inside your main array and use `reduce` inside those sub arrays to sum up the months data.

```js
var data = [
  [{
    jan: 10,
    feb: 20,
    mar: 30,
    type: "one"
  },
  {
    jan: 20,
    feb: 10,
    mar: 40,
    type: "one"
  }],
  [
    {
    jan: 10,
    feb: 20,
    mar: 30,
    type: "two"
  },
  {
    jan: 20,
    feb: 10,
    mar: 40,
    type: "two"
  }]
]

var newData = data.map(function(arr){
  return arr.reduce(function(acc, ele, i){
    if(i === 0){
      acc = ele;
    }
    else{
      var keys= Object.keys(ele);
      keys.splice(keys.indexOf("type"), 1);
      keys.forEach(function(key){
         acc[key] += ele[key];
      })
    }
    return acc;
  },{});
});
console.log(newData)
```

Comment: what do you do for other month's?

Comment: Hi @NinaScholz, updated my answer for variable months.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a hash table for the object with the same `type` and add all values of properties which are not `type`.

```js
var data = [[{ jan: 10, feb: 20, mar: 30, type: "one" }, { jan: 20, feb: 10, mar: 40, type: "one" }], [{ jan: 10, feb: 20, mar: 30, type: "two" }, { jan: 20, feb: 10, mar: 40, type: "two" }]],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    grouped = [];

data.forEach(function (a) {
    a.forEach(function (o) {
        if (!hash[o.type]) {
            hash[o.type] = { type: o.type };
            grouped.push(hash[o.type]);
        }
        Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
            if (k === 'type') {
                return;
            }
            hash[o.type][k] = (hash[o.type][k] || 0) + o[k];
        });
    });
});

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Please choose to close such question as duplicate instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use `reduce` and `forEach`

```
var output = Object.values( data.reduce( function( a, c ){
  c.forEach( function( item ){
     a[ item.type ] = a[ item.type ] || { jan: 0, feb: 0, mar: 0, type: item.type };
     a[ item.type ].jan += item.jan; 
     a[ item.type ].feb += item.feb;
     a[ item.type ].mar += item.mar;
  });
  return a;
}, {}));
```

**Demo**

```js
var data = [
  [{
    jan: 10,
    feb: 20,
    mar: 30,
    type: "one"
  },
  {
    jan: 20,
    feb: 10,
    mar: 40,
    type: "one"
  }],
  [
    {
    jan: 10,
    feb: 20,
    mar: 30,
    type: "two"
  },
  {
    jan: 20,
    feb: 10,
    mar: 40,
    type: "two"
  }]
];

var output = Object.values( data.reduce( function( a, c ){
  c.forEach( function( item ){
     a[ item.type ] = a[ item.type ] || { jan: 0, feb: 0, mar: 0, type: item.type };
     a[ item.type ].jan += item.jan;
     a[ item.type ].feb += item.feb;
     a[ item.type ].mar += item.mar;
  });
  return a;
}, {}));

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#reduce` to group your data based on the `type` value. Use `array#forEach` to iterate through each array.

```js
var data = [ [{ jan: 10, feb: 20, mar: 30, type: "one" }, { jan: 20, feb: 10, mar: 40, type: "one" }], [ { jan: 10, feb: 20, mar: 30, type: "two" }, { jan: 20, feb: 10, mar: 40, type: "two" }] ];
var result = Object.values(data.reduce((r,a) => {
  a.forEach(o => {
    r[o.type] = r[o.type] || Object.assign({'type': o.type});
    Object.keys(o).forEach(k => {
      if(k !== 'type')
        r[o.type][k] = (r[o.type][k] || 0) + o[k];
    });
  });
  return r;
},{}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data.reduce((a,c) => {
    return a.concat(c.reduce((a2,c2) => {
        if(Object.keys(a2).length === 0) return c2;
        return Object.assign({}, a2, {jan: a2.jan + c2.jan, feb: a2.feb + c2.feb, mar: a2.mar + c2.mar})
    },{}))
},[])
```

Nested reduce fully immutable solution.