# Group by and sum array of hashes in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have following array of hashes and want to convert it into an array like the one at the bottom of the post.

```js
var responseData = [
  {deviceType: "Smartphone", deviceCount: 14},
  {deviceType: "Tablet", deviceCount: 11},
  {deviceType: "Notebook", deviceCount: 3},
  {deviceType: "Desktop", deviceCount: 2},
  {deviceType: "Smartphone", deviceCount: 1},
  {deviceType: "Tablet", deviceCount: 10},
  {deviceType: "Notebook", deviceCount: 30},
  {deviceType: "Desktop", deviceCount: 20}
];

function dataMapper(responseData){
  let series = [];
  if(responseData && responseData.length){
  responseData.forEach(function(resource){
  existingElement = series.filter(function (item) {
      return item.deviceType === resource.deviceType;
    });
  if (existingElement) {
    deviceCount = existingElement[0].deviceCount + resource.deviceCount;
    existingElement[0].deviceCount = deviceCount
  }else{
    series[0].push({deviceType: resource.deviceType, y: resource.deviceCount});
  }
    });
  }
  return series
}

console.log(dataMapper(responseData))
```

I want to convert this into:

```
var expectedResult = [
    {deviceType: "Smartphone", deviceCount: 15},
    {deviceType: "Tablet", deviceCount: 21},
    {deviceType: "Notebook", deviceCount: 33},
    {deviceType: "Desktop", deviceCount: 22}
];
```

Comment: your filter method is not working correctly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sum javascript object propertyA values with same object propertyB in array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19233283/sum-javascript-object-propertya-values-with-same-object-propertyb-in-array-of-ob)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using an ES6 Map and `reduce`:

```js
const responseData = [{deviceType: "Smartphone", deviceCount: 14},{deviceType: "Tablet", deviceCount: 11},{deviceType: "Notebook", deviceCount: 3},{deviceType: "Desktop", deviceCount: 2},{deviceType: "Smartphone", deviceCount: 1},{deviceType: "Tablet", deviceCount: 10},{deviceType: "Notebook", deviceCount: 30},{deviceType: "Desktop", deviceCount: 20}];

const result = Array.from(
    responseData.reduce( 
        (acc, o) => (acc.get(o.deviceType).deviceCount += o.deviceCount, acc),
        new Map(responseData.map( ({deviceType}) => [deviceType, {deviceType, deviceCount: 0} ] )) 
    ).values()
);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I could not imagine that this could be done even more inefficiently than what the OP tried to do... :)

Answer (score 2):

Its much easier if you use a hashtable and build up the result in parallel:

```
 const hash = {}, result = [];

for(const {deviceType, deviceCount} of responseData){
  if(hash[deviceType]){
     hash[deviceType].deviceCount += deviceCount;
  } else {
     result.push(hash[deviceType] = {deviceType, deviceCount});
  }
}
```

If you really want to iterate over the array, you should use `find` instead of `filter`:

```
const result = [];

for(const {deviceType, deviceCount} of responseData){
  const exists = result.find(device => device.deviceType === deviceType);
 if(exists){
   exists.deviceCount += deviceCount;
  } else {
   result.push({deviceType, deviceCount });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take a hash table as reference to the counting object and return the array with the objects.

```js
var responseData = [{ deviceType: "Smartphone", deviceCount: 14 }, { deviceType: "Tablet", deviceCount: 11 }, { deviceType: "Notebook", deviceCount: 3 }, { deviceType: "Desktop", deviceCount: 2 }, { deviceType: "Smartphone", deviceCount: 1 }, { deviceType: "Tablet", deviceCount: 10 }, { deviceType: "Notebook", deviceCount: 30 }, { deviceType: "Desktop", deviceCount: 20 }],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    result = responseData.reduce(function (r, o) {
        if (!hash[o.deviceType]) {
            hash[o.deviceType] = { deviceType: o.deviceType, deviceCount: 0 };
            r.push(hash[o.deviceType]);
        }
        hash[o.deviceType].deviceCount += o.deviceCount;
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

Another solution could be to use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and get later an array of all counted devices.

```js
var responseData = [{ deviceType: "Smartphone", deviceCount: 14 }, { deviceType: "Tablet", deviceCount: 11 }, { deviceType: "Notebook", deviceCount: 3 }, { deviceType: "Desktop", deviceCount: 2 }, { deviceType: "Smartphone", deviceCount: 1 }, { deviceType: "Tablet", deviceCount: 10 }, { deviceType: "Notebook", deviceCount: 30 }, { deviceType: "Desktop", deviceCount: 20 }],
    result = Array.from(
        responseData.reduce((map, { deviceType, deviceCount }) => map.set(deviceType, (map.get(deviceType) || 0) + deviceCount), new Map),
        ([ deviceType, deviceCount ]) => ({ deviceType, deviceCount })
    );

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the way where we bring your expected result is by doing like this:

```js
var responseData = [{
        deviceType: "Smartphone",
        deviceCount: 14
      },
      {
        deviceType: "Tablet",
        deviceCount: 11
      },
      {
        deviceType: "Notebook",
        deviceCount: 3
      },
      {
        deviceType: "Desktop",
        deviceCount: 2
      },
      {
        deviceType: "Smartphone",
        deviceCount: 1
      },
      {
        deviceType: "Tablet",
        deviceCount: 10
      },
      {
        deviceType: "Notebook",
        deviceCount: 30
      },
      {
        deviceType: "Desktop",
        deviceCount: 20
      }
    ];
    var pushedType = [];
    var summedData = [];

    for (var i in responseData) {
      if (pushedType.indexOf(responseData[i].deviceType) === -1) {
        summedData.push(responseData[i]);
        pushedType.push(responseData[i].deviceType);
      } else {
        summedData[pushedType.indexOf(responseData[i].deviceType)].deviceCount += responseData[i].deviceCount;
        }
      }

      $(".result").html(JSON.stringify(summedData))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="result"></div>
```

Hope it helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use [lodash](http://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5)

```
let result = _.groupBy(responseData , 'deviceType');
result = Object.keys(result).map(key => {
   return  { 
       deviceType: key,
       deviceCount: _.sumBy(result[key], 'deviceCount')} ;
});
```

or with `Array.reduce()`:

```
let transformObj = {};
   responseData.reduce((prev,cur) =>{
      const key = cur.deviceType;
      if(!prev[key]){
         prev[key] =  0;
      }
      prev[key] += cur.deviceCount;

      return prev;
   },transformObj);

  const results = Object.keys(transformObj).map(key => {
      return {
           deviceType: key,
           deviceCount: transformObj[key]
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I added this fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/6zuux7jq/6/

```js
var responseData = [
  {deviceType: "Smartphone", deviceCount: 14},
  {deviceType: "Tablet", deviceCount: 11},
  {deviceType: "Notebook", deviceCount: 3},
  {deviceType: "Desktop", deviceCount: 2},
  {deviceType: "Smartphone", deviceCount: 1},
  {deviceType: "Tablet", deviceCount: 10},
  {deviceType: "Notebook", deviceCount: 30},
  {deviceType: "Desktop", deviceCount: 20}
];
 
function dataMapper(responseData){
  var series = {};
  if(responseData && responseData.length){
  responseData.forEach(function(element){
       series[element.deviceType] = Number.isInteger(series[element.deviceType]) ? series[element.deviceType] + element.deviceCount : element.deviceCount
    });
  }
  var tmp = []
  for (var i in series) {
    tmp.push({deviceType: i, deviceCount: series[i]})
  }
  return tmp
}

console.log(dataMapper(responseData))
```

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const results = []
var temp = {};

responseData.map(function(item){
    temp[item.deviceType] = (temp[item.deviceType] || 0) + item.deviceCount;;
})

Object.keys(temp).forEach(function(key) {
    results.push({ deviceType: key, deviceCount: temp[key]});
})

console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
responseData.forEach(function(item) {
if (expectedResult[item.deviceType] == null) {
   expectedResult[item.deviceType] = item;
} else {
expectedResult[item.deviceType].deviceCount += item.deviceCount;
}
});
```