# How to join list items on property with equal value using ngrx & typescript

Tags: typescript, ngrx

Lets say I have a list in my state:

```
list: SomeObj[];
```

where:

`SomeObj: {name: string, val: number}`

I then have the following items in the SomeObj[]:

```
{name: Alice,  val: 1}
{name: Bob,    val: 2}
{name: Bob,    val: 2}
{name: Conrad, val: 3}
```

How do I subscribe on something like:

```
{name: Alice,  val: 1}
{name: Bob,    val: 4}
{name: Conrad, val: 3}
```

where I join on the name property while doing sum on the val property.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sum javascript object propertyA values with same object propertyB in array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19233283/sum-javascript-object-propertya-values-with-same-object-propertyb-in-array-of-ob)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a selector that groups the results by name:

```
getSumByName = createSelector(
 state => state.list,
 list => groupBy(list, name)
  )
```

You can read how to implement a groupBy function here:

[What is the most efficient method to groupby on a JavaScript array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/what-is-the-most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-a-javascript-array-of-objects)