# What does the 'get' method refer to on the accumulator in the Array.prototype.reduce method's callback?

Tags: javascript

The title might seem quite verbose, but in reference to this answer posted in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37623524/4111415

I was wondering what the `let count = prev.get(curr.key) || 0;` actually meant. As far as I am aware the accumulator (`prev`) is just a number; what is the `get` method actually doing here? I have looked at the MDN documenation to no avail: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

```js
let objArr = [
  {key: 'Mon Sep 23 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400', val: 42},
  {key: 'Mon Sep 24 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400', val: 78},
  {key: 'Mon Sep 25 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400', val: 23},
  {key: 'Mon Sep 23 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400', val: 54}
];

// first, convert data into a Map with reduce
let counts = objArr.reduce((prev, curr) => {
  let count = prev.get(curr.key) || 0;
  prev.set(curr.key, curr.val + count);
  return prev;
}, new Map());

// then, map your counts object back to an array
let reducedObjArr = [...counts].map(([key, value]) => {
  return {key, value}
})

console.log(reducedObjArr);
```

Comment: In your code, it's https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get. `new Map()`, the initial value, is not a number!

Comment: If you vote down, specify the reason or edit the question please. I don't see any reason to do that here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As far as I am aware the accumulator (prev) is just a number

No, this isn't always the case. If a value is specified in the `initialValue` argument of [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), the accumulator (in this case `prev`) will take the value of that initial value.

The initial value in your example is `new Map()` which is a map object. The [`Map` prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get) includes the `.get` method, which is used to retrieve a specific value from the map object (similar to object key-value pair retrieval).

Thus, your `.get` method is referring to the `Map` object, not a number.

Answer (score 0):

`prev`, i.e the `accumulator`, is actually a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Map) object, which is passed as the last parameter to the [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/reduce) function.

Answer (score 0):

In the provided example the accumulator is an instance of [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object (instead of a number), that is being passed as a last argument ([initial value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Parameters)) to reduce.

Answer (score 0):

[`Map#get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get) is part of the prototype of [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

You could simplify the reduce by returning the map directly, because of the [fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) of `Map#set`.

For getting a formatted result, you could use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) with mapping function.

---

Maybe you are a bit irritated by the use of `prev` and `curr`. If you take instead `map` and `item`, you might get better the types of the variables.

```js
let objArr = [{ key: 'Mon Sep 23 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400', val: 42 }, { key: 'Mon Sep 24 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400', val: 78 }, { key: 'Mon Sep 25 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400', val: 23 }, { key: 'Mon Sep 23 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400', val: 54 }],
    counts = objArr.reduce(
        (map, item) => map.set(item.key, item.val + (map.get(item.key) || 0)),
        new Map
    ),
    reducedObjArr = Array.from(counts, ([key, value]) => ({ key, value }));

console.log(reducedObjArr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```