# Find duplicate value in array of objects and sum values of some key

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects which look like below

```
    let array1 = [
    { 'id': 356, 'name': 'Apple', 'quantity': 150 },
    { 'id': 356, 'name': 'Apple', 'quantity': 200 },
    { 'id': 370, 'name': 'Orange', 'quantity': 200 }

];
```

I need to **sum quantity** and return new array if duplicate id is found

**Expected result**

```
[
        { 'id': 356, 'name': 'Apple', 'quantity': 350 },
        { 'id': 370, 'name': 'Orange', 'quantity': 200 }

     ]
```

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19233283/sum-javascript-object-propertya-values-with-same-object-propertyb-in-array-of-ob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
 let array1 = [
    { 'id': 356, 'name': 'Apple', 'quantity': 150 },
    { 'id': 356, 'name': 'Apple', 'quantity': 200 },
    { 'id': 370, 'name': 'Orange', 'quantity': 200 }

];

var result = Enumerable.From(array1)
        .GroupBy("$.name", null,
                 function (key, g) {
                     return {
                       name: key,
                       quantity: g.Sum("$.quantity")
                     }
        })
        .ToArray();

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/linq.js/2.2.0.2/linq.min.js"></script>
```