# Array of objects to another array sumarized

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm new to JS and I'm having issues to sum values from one array into another one summarized.

I have this data:

```
const data = [
  {
    category: 'personal',
    amount: 80000,
    month: 'Diciembre',
  },
  {
    category: 'comida',
    amount: 207000,
    month: 'Diciembre',
  },
  {
    category: 'comida',
    amount: 43000,
    month: 'Diciembre',
  },
  {
    category: 'salidas',
    amount: 124000,
    month: 'Diciembre',
  },
  {
    category: 'casa',
    amount: 450505,
    month: 'Diciembre',
  },
  {
    category: 'casa',
    amount: 500000,
    month: 'Diciembre',
  },
  {
    category: 'varios',
    amount: 260000,
    month: 'Diciembre',
  },
  {
    category: 'casa',
    amount: 296300,
    month: 'Diciembre',
  },
];
```

And I want to convert it in something like:

```
const dataSummarized = [
  {
    category: 'personal',
    amount: TOTAL_AMOUNT_PERSONAL_CATEGORY
    month: 'Diciembre',
  },
  {
    category: 'comida',
    amount: TOTAL_AMOUNT_COMIDA_CATEGORY
    month: 'Diciembre',
  },
  {
    category: 'salidas',
    amount: TOTAL_AMOUNT_SALIDAS_CATEGORY,
    month: 'Diciembre',
  },
  {
    category: 'casa',
    amount: TOTAL_AMOUNT_CASA_CATEGORY,
    month: 'Diciembre',
  }
];
```

I've tried several options, but without results.

Some of the solutions I've tried are posted here [Sum javascript object propertyA values with same object propertyB in array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19233283/sum-javascript-object-propertya-values-with-same-object-propertyb-in-array-of-ob)

Evidently, I'm missing something because I couldn't make it work :(

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please share what you've tried based on the answers from [Sum javascript object propertyA values with same object propertyB in array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19233283) and what didn't work, otherwise, people will most likely point you back in the direction of the answers from there.

Comment: _"I've tried several options"_ - consider adding these efforts to the question as [mcve]s?

Comment: Have a look at `Array.reduce`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can then use `Array.reduce()` to group items by category, then month (I presume you want expense totals per month).

We create a grouping key based on category and month, then sum the total amount for each of these keys:

```js
const data = [ { category: 'personal', amount: 80000, month: 'Diciembre', }, { category: 'comida', amount: 207000, month: 'Diciembre', }, { category: 'comida', amount: 43000, month: 'Diciembre', }, { category: 'salidas', amount: 124000, month: 'Diciembre', }, { category: 'casa', amount: 450505, month: 'Diciembre', }, { category: 'casa', amount: 500000, month: 'Diciembre', }, { category: 'varios', amount: 260000, month: 'Diciembre', }, { category: 'casa', amount: 296300, month: 'Diciembre', }, ]; 

const result = Object.values(data.reduce((acc, { category, month, amount }) => { 
    const key = `${category}-${month}`;
    acc[key] = acc[key] || { category, month, amount: 0 };
    acc[key].amount += amount;
    return acc;
}, {}));

console.log('Result:', result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```