# how to merge two objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to add the values of data with similar keys of two or more rows in JavaScript shown below:

```
[{name: 'Co', phonenumber: '754', commission: 180}
 {name: 'Co', phonenumber: '754', commission: 0}
 {name: 'Co', phonenumber: '715', commission: 180}
 {name: 'Co', phonenumber: '715', commission: 50}]
```

So, the result I want is below:

```
[{name: 'Co', phonenumber: '754', commission: 180}
 {name: 'Co', phonenumber: '715', commission: 230}]
```

commission property should add and rest will be merged.
Thanks

Comment: Maybe [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19233283/sum-javascript-object-propertya-values-with-the-same-object-propertyb-in-an-arra/76616118#76616118) could help you!