# How to group data-items, and merge their properties by summing up related values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, merge, reduce

Given is an array of data-items where one needs to total the values of each property where its key differs from an additionally provided property-name (which serves as grouping key).

Thus for a the grouping key `name` and sample-data like ...

```
[{
  name: "Name1",
  amt: 100,
  tax: 10,
  total: 110,
}, {
  name: "Name2",
  amt: 50,
  tax: 5,
  total: 55,
}, {
  name: "Name1",
  amt: 70,
  tax: 7,
  total: 77,
}]
```

... the expected result is ...

```
[{
  name: "Name1",
  amt: 170,
  tax: 17,
  total: 187,
}, {
  name: "Name2",
  amt: 50,
  tax: 5,
  total: 55,
}]
```

Is there a method or reference which enables one of producing an output like the one above?

Comment: `Array.prototype.reduce`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sum JavaScript object propertyA values with the same object propertyB in an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19233283/sum-javascript-object-propertya-values-with-the-same-object-propertyb-in-an-arra)

Comment: I vote against closing the above Q. as duplicate because not a single answer of the above comment's linked thread does provide an entirely generic solution (which is possible to achieve) to the OP's specific problem. The so far provided answers both are heading into that direction with the one of _**Mr. Polywhirl**_ being fully generic and the one of _**Alexander Nenashev**_ being generic in most parts.

Comment: @JijiG2A ... Regarding the so far provided answers / approaches, are there any questions left?

Answer (score 0):

From my above comment ...

> *"I vote against closing the above Q. as duplicate because not a single answer of the above comment's linked thread does provide an entirely generic solution (which is possible to achieve) to the OP's specific problem. The so far provided answers both are heading into that direction with the one of ***Mr. Polywhirl*** being fully generic and the one of ***Alexander Nenashev*** being generic in most parts."*

It is possible to implement the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method's [reducer callback function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#description) in a fully generic way.

In order to provide the grouping key's name one needs to pass an object as [initial value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#how_reduce_works_with_an_initial_value) to the `reduce` method's [2nd parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#parameters).

This very object might look like that ...

```
{ key: 'name', result: {} }
```

... and does also serve as accumulator/collector object which gets passed on with each iteration step. Any implementation would aggregate the final data-structure on the collector's initially empty `result` object. Choosing an object provides the advantage of delivering the final result in a readable generic data-format like ...

```
{
  Name1: {
    name: "Name1",
    amt: 170,
    tax: 17,
    total: 187,
  },
  Name2: {
    name: "Name2",
    amt: 50,
    tax: 5,
    total: 55,
  }
}
```

... while also being able of utilizing the [nullish coalescing assignment operator / `??=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment) for either creating the initial data of a non existing group or accessing the data of an already existing group.

Back to the currently processed array-item which is unknown by each of its property names.

Here one does take advantage of [destructuring assignments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) like [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring) and [rest property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#rest_property). And since the provided grouping key name has been provided as `key` and assigned to a the variable `key,` one is in need of the syntax for [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#computed_object_property_names_and_destructuring). Thus, each currently processed array-item which is unknown by each of its property names has to be destructured like ...

```
{ [key]: keyValue, ...restData }
```

... where the variable `keyValue` hold's the `name`-keys's value and `restData` is an object which features every other key-value pair (entry) than the `name`-key based one.

As for the OP's first data-item ...

```
{
  name: "Name1",
  amt: 100,
  tax: 10,
  total: 110,
}
```

... `keyValue` got assigned `"Name1"` and `restData` does refer ...

```
{
  amt: 100,
  tax: 10,
  total: 110,
}
```

In order to compute the total amount of each of a group's equally named property value one does iterate the [`entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) of each `restData` object. [For each](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) key-value pair of `restData` one does (again with the help of a nullish coalescing assignment) either initially create the data-key based property and does assign zero/`0` to it or/and one does sum up (total) the value of an already existing property by the current data-value.

The OP's requested final data-structure gets achieved by passing the returned `result` object to [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values).

```js
function groupByKeyAndTotalAnyOtherValue(
  // - the destructured accumulator/collector object.
  { key = "", result = {} },
  // - the destructured currently processed array-item
  //   which is unknown by each of its property names.
  { [key]: keyValue, ...restData },
) {
  // - access an existing group or create the minimum group data.
  const group = result[keyValue] ??= { [key]: keyValue };

  Object
    // - get all entries of the unknown rest data.
    .entries(restData)
    .forEach(([dataKey, dataValue]) =>

      // - compute the total amount of each of
      //   a group's equally named property value.
      group[dataKey] = (group[dataKey] ??= 0) + dataValue
    );

  // - pass-on/return the accumulator's/collector's current state.
  return { key, result };
}
console.log(
  'totaled values as nested object ...',
  sampleData
    .reduce(
      groupByKeyAndTotalAnyOtherValue, { key: 'name', result: {} }
    )
    .result
);
console.log(
  'totaled values as array of objects ...',
  Object
    .values(
      sampleData
        .reduce(
          groupByKeyAndTotalAnyOtherValue, { key: 'name', result: {} }
        )
        .result
    )
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script>
  const sampleData = [{
    name: "Name1",
    amt: 100,
    tax: 10,
    total: 110,
  }, {
    name: "Name2",
    amt: 50,
    tax: 5,
    total: 55,
  }, {
    name: "Name1",
    amt: 70,
    tax: 7,
    total: 77,
  }];
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could reduce each object into a map by the key value. For each item, loop over the keys and ignore the `key` param.

Sum the incoming `item[k]` onto the `existing[k]` entry.

Finally, return the `values()` of the `Map` and spread the iterator into a new `Array` object.

```js
const reduceBy = (data, key) =>
  [...data.reduce((map, item) => {
    const existing = map.get(item[key]) ?? { [key]: item[key] };
    for (let k in item) {
      if (k !== key) {
        existing[k] = (existing[k] ?? 0) + item[k];
      }
    }
    return map.set(item[key], existing);
  }, new Map).values()];

const
  input = [
    { name: "Name1", amt: 100, tax: 10, total: 110 },
    { name: "Name2", amt:  50, tax:  5, total:  55 },
    { name: "Name1", amt:  70, tax:  7, total:  77 }
  ],
  expected = [
    { name: "Name1", amt: 170, tax: 17, total: 187 },
    { name: "Name2", amt:  50, tax:  5, total:  55 }
  ],
  actual = reduceBy(input, 'name');

console.log(JSON.stringify(actual) === JSON.stringify(expected));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: All of the JavaScript "group by" questions have been answered...