# algorithm sum and group by Array data

Tags: javascript, vb.net, algorithm, group-by, sum

I need some help., i am using vb.net and javascript.

I have  dataset like this,

```
Row     Price     ProductID     Region

1       100       12345         JK1

2       100       12345         JK2

3       100       23456         JK1

4       100       23456         JK2
```

i need the result JK1 = 200 and JK2 = 200. Result is SUM all price with grup by region. May be in SQL this is so simple, but in programming i haven't try.

I need the algoritm in vb.net or javascript. The problem is, the region have a lot of variation that i dont know how much that is.

can some one help?

Comment: you might like to see this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11199653/javascript-sum-and-group-by-of-json-data

Comment: get it into javascript array can do something like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/3UsJa/

Comment: @noctis i don't need the code, i just need the algorithm ..

Comment: @nnnnnn this is not simple that you imagine, i try a lot of way, try to build algorithm .. just check the region? i say that the region contains too many variation, looping it don't give the solution. sorry for my bad language, but i am not that stupid. thanks.

Comment: Why don't you try DataTable.Compute Method in VB.NET?

Comment: if just looping, i will not post in this forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to use Dictionaries for this purpose. I don't really have much experience with datasets but it doesn't really matter for this example. I will just define input as a List(Of RegionPrice) with

```
Structure RegionPrice
  Dim Region as String
  Dim Price as Integer
End Structure
[...]
Dim Data as List(Of RegionPrice) = ....
```

Just loop through your data and get the Region and Price of the current item. Then

```
Dim dictSum as New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
For i = 0 to Data.Count - 1
  If dictSum.ContainsKey(Data(i).Region) Then
    dictSum(Data(i).Region) += Data(i).Price
  Else
    dictSum.Add(Data(i).Region,Data(i).Price)
  End If
Next
```

You will then have the sums you want for each region in the Dictionary.
Maybe that helps for these kinds of problems.

Answer (score 0):

[DataTable.Compute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Method can help you:

```
Dim sumPrice As Object = dataTable.Compute("Sum(Price)", "Region ='" + "JK1" + "'")
```