# Ext JS modified view of an existing store

Tags: javascript, extjs

In Ext JS there is a chained store that allows us to sit on top of an existing store and perform grouping, filtering and sorting of the underlying store without affecting the actual data in the store.

Is there some way we could do something similar but provide a function that would aggregate the data in the store, which could then be used by another component to view the aggregation?

For example, lets say I have a store that has a collection of objects with a date and a value. I have a grid that shows every item in that store.  But I want to have another component that shows the data aggregated by day.  So I want to take that raw data and collect all items that have the same date and sum the values.

I know that grids have grouping summary options, but I don't want all of the data to appear in the grid alongside the summary, just the grouping summary.

One component looks like:

`|Date  |Value|
|1/1/18|1    |
|1/1/18|5    |
|2/1/18|1    |
...`

The other:

`|1/1/18|2/1/18|etc.|
|6     |1     |etc.|`

Comment: `But I want to have another component that shows the data aggregated by day` can you explain about your second component which xtype you have used ?

Comment: Both components are `Ext.grid.Panel`s. One is a simple vertical grid with two columns date and value. The other is a horizontal grid where the header is a week's worth of days and the aggregated values should be displayed in the column

Comment: As far as I know, you want to implement that by hand. The store aggregate functions may come handy, but you may have to implement the actual aggregation logic yourself.

Comment: Ok, so if I have two grids each needs to be backed by a store, so how would I manually take the data in store 1 and convert it to the required data for store 2? Preferably in such a way that if I edit the data in store 1 the data in store 2 is also updated.

Comment: You can do like this http://jsfiddle.net/R3p4c/2/  
 ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/11199847/3728901 )

Comment: @DoNhuVy this does not help me, the issue is related to use of ExtJS grid panel with a different view on an existing store. I can easily perform the aggregation, I just want to know how I can hook up the two stores so that ExtJS handles the synchronisation of the components.